# Concept of return for assets which don't have a well defined price

Tags: financial-markets, private-equity

Much of financial theory seems to assume that assets have a price, for example the concepts of return or volatility. Is there any way to operationalize these concepts for assets which don't have a well defined price, for example private equity?

Comment: Here are some examples of metrics for private equity: https://docs.preqin.com/misc/Performance_Ratios_and_Example.pdf

Comment: According to Global Investment Performance Standards (GIPS) PE performance should be presented with IRR (Internal Rate of Return) among other stats. Comparison to public equity is indeed difficult; the PME (Public Market Equivalent) formulas, of which KS-PME is the best known, provide a (partial) possible solution. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_Market_Equivalent

Comment: You still pay a price to buy private assets and hope to make a return by selling them to the public market someday at a higher price. So in a sense it is not that different in concept.